# boost serialization - deriving from polymorphic archive

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

How do I create a class which derives from `boost::archive::polymorphic_xml_oarchive`? I'm assuming this is the whole purpose of the polymorphic archives? Perhaps I'm wrong.

Anyway, I want something like

```
class MyArchive: public boost::serialization::polymorphic_xml_oarchive
{
    public:
        // custom behavior for select types
        void save(int const & t){}
};
```

I have found examples for creating custom boost archives but none using the polymorphic archive types. I have no idea what classes to derive from and what member function signatures to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the whole idea of `polymorphic_archive` is to implement that interface (so clients do not have to know about particular (future) implementations at compile time).

So no, you wouldn't (usually/necessarily) *derive* from an implementation. You would implement the interface using your own means<sup>1</sup>.

This therefore assumes you have some kind of (non-polymorphic) archive implementation already lying around. If this happens to be an archive implementation that satisfies the requirements for the Boost Serialization archive concept, you can use the ready-made adaptors from boost.

#### Adapting as a polymorphic archive:

There is an extensive **[class diagram](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/class_diagram.html)** with prose descriptions of the responsibilities of each class in the hierarchy.

Again, the relevant bits:

> As can be seen in the class diagram and the header files, this implementation is just a composition of the polymorphic interface and the standard template driven implementation. This composition is accomplished by the templates `polymorphic_iarchive_route.hpp` and `polymorphic_oarchive_route.hpp`. As these contain no code specific to the particular implementation archive, they can be **used to create a polymorphic archive implementation from any functioning templated archive implementation**.

#### The Archive Concept

The Archive concept, straight from **the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/archive_reference.html)**:

> The Archive concept specifies the functions that a class must implement to in
>   order to be used to serialize Serializable types. The library implements a
>   family of archives appropriate for different purposes. This section describes
>   how they have been implemented and one way one can implement his own archive
>   class. Our discussion will focus on archives used for loading as the
>   hierarchy is exactly analogous for archives used for saving data.
>
> Our archives have been factored in to a tree of classes in order to minimize
>    repetition of code. This is shown in the accompanying class diagram. Any
>    class which fullfills the following requirements will function as a loading
>    archive.
>
> #### Minimum Requirements
>
> The archive class is derived from:
>
> ```
>   template<class Archive>
>   detail::common_iarchive;
> ```
>
> An instance of the this template handles all the "bookkeeping" associated
>   with serialization. In order to be a functional only the following additional
>   functions must be declared:
>
> ```
>   void load(T &t);
> ```
>
> This function must be implemented for all primitive data types. This can be
>    accomplished through the use of a member template or explicit declarations
>    for all primitive types.
>
> ```
>   void load_binary(void *address, std::size_t size);
> ```
>
> This function should size bytes from the archive, and copy them in to memory starting at address address.
>
> ```
>   friend class boost::archive::load_access;
> ```
>
> In addition, such a class must provide a the following friend declaration
>    grant access to the core serialization library to the functions of this
>    class.
>
> So, the most trivial implementation of an input archive would look like this:
>
> ```
> #include <boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp>
>
> /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
> // class trivial_iarchive - read serialized objects from a input text stream
> class trivial_iarchive : 
>     public boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<trivial_iarchive>
> {
>     // permit serialization system privileged access to permit
>     // implementation of inline templates for maximum speed.
>     friend class boost::archive::load_access;
>
>     // member template for loading primitive types.
>     // Override for any types/templates that special treatment
>     template<class T>
>     void load(T & t);
>
> public:
>     //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>     // public interface used by programs that use the
>     // serialization library
>
>     // archives are expected to support this function
>     void load_binary(void *address, std::size_t count);
> };
> ```

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, there could be reasons to derive the implementation of your archive from an existing archive, but

- that would be an implementation detail, it's not essential to providing the polymorphic_[io]archive interface
- it would usually make more sense to derive your *static* archive type from an existing archive type and **adapt** *that* using the `polymorphic_[io]archive_route` classes discussed above

Comment: I think I understand now. My polymorphic archive should not derive from, for example, polymorphic_text_iarchive, but from polymorphic_iarchive_route, replacing the parameters of route with my own implementation as described in the documentation.

Comment: @chuck1 That's the typical design indeed. Of course, you're free to implement the interface directly without the aid of `polymorphic_iarchive_route` but (a) I'm not convinced it will be easier (b) I'm not sure it will be easy to run the Archive test cases in that case